# Correct url's to asset files generated by webpack in express

Tags: express, webpack

How do you handle links to asset files generated by webpack, when you use .ejs templating engine, if file includes [contenthash] for caching files in browser?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out HTMLWebpackPlugin

Comment: @felixmosh If I understand right, it will generate HTML file which I can put on production server, but I am not creating SPA. I am building multiple page site, using ejs as templating, and cant figure out, how to connect asset links. If I will generate my JS bundle as main.[hash].js for caching, I will need to manually update correct links whenever I push on to production. Isn't there better way? Or the solution is not to generate with hash, instead just main.js?

Comment: You can provide your own template for each chunk, it will inject the bundles.

Comment: @Edjis You should include the info from your previous comment in the question for more clarity. If your pages/template files are generated by webpack it should substitute any assets automatically (with the correct content hash), are you saying it doesn't work for you? What exactly happens and what do you expect/need to happen - give examples ?

Comment: @kidroca Yeah, question wasn't probably clear enough, what I expect to happen. Sorry, kind a new to webpack + express. So correct question/problem I guess is, how to get correct links to assets, if template files is not generated by webpack. One solution, which I googled out, was, to use manifests and express plugin, who can get access to it in .ejs templates. Are there any other solutions?